# Puppeteer unable to run Chrome on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, aws-codebuild

I'm using Karma to test an Angular4 project using ChromeHeadless and all works fine locally.  I've then tried to get this running on AWS CodeBuild.  The initial problem was that the CodeBuild VM does not include chrome headless and so I included the Puppeteer npm package and set the ENV Var accordingly in the Karma conf.  This still works fine locally, but on AWS CodeBuild I get the error ...

`puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-526987/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The build is triggered from standard buildspec.yml executing maven `mvn -B package`.  The angular build/test is done from maven using the eislett/frontend-maven-plugin (v1.4).

Puppeteer v1.0.0
Node v6.10.1
Karma v1.7.1
AWS CodeBuild - Ubuntu / Java / OpenJDK 8

I've seen other posts about additional installs onto the CI machines but CodeBuild spins up a clean VM on each run so thats not an option.  Any suggestions!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally (after over a year!) got this working (without puppeteer).

buildspec.yml - install chrome stable

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
      - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
      - apt-get -y update
      - apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

karma.conf.js - specify port, hostname, listenaddress, disable random, extend timeouts & tolerances

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    captureTimeout: 210000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 210000,
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    listenAddress: 'localhost',
    hostname: 'localhost',
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--password-store=basic',
          '--enable-logging',
          '--v=1'
        ],
      },
    },
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Answer (score 6):

I work on the CodeBuild team. You can either install the missing package during each build as part of your buildspec:

```
  install:
    - apt-get install missing-package
```

Or build a custom environment for use with CodeBuild that contains the missing package:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments/

CodeBuild's environments are open-sourced to help you get started with custom environments:
https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images

Comment: Given that all our projects will be using this, I think a custom environment is the way to go so we dont have to maintain a bunch of scripts as/when things change.  Thanks!

Comment: So I finally managed to get the dependancy issue sorted and now Karma seems to firing up Chrome but I'm now stuck with the age old `ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.` error. Something to do with running as root?  tried `--no-sandbox`.
Has ANYONE got angular/karma/chrome working on AWS CodeBuild?

Comment: It looks like this workaround works for running on CodeBuild: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/158

Comment: Thanks Clare, but as I've said above, I already tried the `--no-sandbox` option and still cant get it to work. (It does fix the run-as-root issue, but not the capture timeout).  I'll keep hacking at it!

Comment: Update: More progress using an older version of chrome.  Now errors about not being able to open display

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ClareLiguori. We're experiencing the same issue bumping from aws/codebuild/standard:5.0 to 6.0. Version 5.0 had it pre-configured (I assume), 6.0 and later does not. Were these intentionally left out in these versions and could you share why? Here's an open issue on it btw: https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/562

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem using Jest & React, using the aws/codebuild/nodejs:7.0.0 CodeBuild image. Here's how I solved it:

In buildspec.yml:

```
# install chromium after updating apt-get (this will install dependencies)
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - sudo apt-get update
      - sudo apt-get --assume-yes install chromium-browser
...
```

In test code:

```
// launch puppeteer with the --no-sandbox option
...
var browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go, though I'm restricted to the OpenJDK8 image.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: This answers the question more accurately.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use aws docker image with chrome - [aws/codebuild/standard:3.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/tree/master/ubuntu/standard/3.0).
Edit it in the environment panel in your build.